# How to respond to user prompt in Dockerfile?

Tags: git, docker

I am running a command: `RUN ssh -T git@github.com` that prompts the user:

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (123.45.67.89)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:asdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfas.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

It seems like docker is skipping the input, which defaults to no. This leads to my problem.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8

WORKDIR /root

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common build-essential git maven

RUN mkdir /root/.ssh
ADD .ssh /root/.ssh
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub

# make sure your domain is accepted
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN ssh -T git@github.com # this line asks for user input, how can I input 'yes' here?

RUN mkdir app && cd app
RUN git init && git remote add origin git@github.com:org/app.git && git pull origin master

# build app

CMD ["java","-jar","app.jar","-s"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

How can I make docker enter `yes` as user input response for `ssh -T` command?

Comment: You avoid the prompt. Find out why `ssh` is asking for confirmation, then configure it to *not* ask.

Comment: You should probably run any `git` commands outside Docker.  This avoids some significant problems around credentials (don't leak your ssh key into the image!), layer caching (if the `git pull` command hasn't changed then Docker won't repeat it), and building things that aren't committed (either a non-default branch or your local development tree).

Comment: (`docker run --rm your-image cat /root/.ssh/id_ed25519` will retrieve the private key; anyone who has the image can do this without restriction.  If you've `docker push`ed the image anywhere, you should treat that key as compromised, remove it from your GitHub account, _etc._)